# Passing value from code-behind to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using a jQueryUI ProgressBar to show users how much allowed file storage they have used. The percentage is calculated in code-behind and should be passed to Javascript.

**Aspx Code**

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var pct = document.getElementById("filesPercentage").value;
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: pct
                });
            });
        </script>
    </asp:Content>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
      ...
     <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="filesPercentage" />                      
     <div id="progressbar"></div>         
      ...
    </asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   filesPercentage.Value = "85";
}
```

It seems like it can't get the percentage number from the hidden field. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the hidden field contain the value if you view the source?

Comment: filesPercentage is likely not going to be id of the control once it is rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your hidden field is a server control it could be that the ID is getting generated to something other than `filesPercentage` (probably something like `ctl00_ctl00_filesPercentage`)

- You may need to apply the generated client ID to your javascript `document.getElementById("<%=filesPercentage.ClientID%>").value;`
- Or use another way of selecting the hidden value, such as `$('[hidden's parent element] input[type="hidden"]').val()`

---

additionally, it looks like progressbar value is expecting a number, so you may need to do `value: pct * 1` or `value: parseInt(pct)`

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/QyZSs/

Comment: Good job on solving my first problem and anticipating the next problem I would have run into. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the rendered id of your hidden input

```
var pct = document.getElementById("<%=filesPercentage.ClientID%>").value;
```

and from the moment that you run the input on server its better to use the `asp:HiddenField` and not the `input`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var pct = document.getElementById("<%=filesPercentage.ClientID %>").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

.net will modify the id you give a control to ensure it is unique, so you are not accessing it with the correct id.  If you give the hidden field a unique class name, you can access the value that way:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="filesPercentage" class="hiddenClass" /> 
var pct = $('.hiddenClass').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cleaner IMHO :-)

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
  value: $("#<%=filesPercentage.ClientID%>").val()
});
```