# Pass value to Jquery function from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery progress bar control on asp.net form to show the percentage of completed work for inspector. Here is the client side function for progress bar.

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                value: 37
            });
        });
    </script>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div id="progressbar"></div>
    </form>
```

Is there any way to set progress bar value from code behind page? Values are read from database.

Comment: You can use a hidden field.

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656328/passing-value-from-code-behind-to-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below steps**

1. First set the `DB` value to `hidden field` on page load. like (`HiddenFieldID.value="37" // from DB`)
2. Use the `hidden field` value to set the value to progress bar in js function as below.

`$(function () {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: $("#<%= HiddenFieldID.ClientID %>").val();
    });
});`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **registerstartupscript** to inject the script from ASP.NET code behind files.

```
myScript = "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"Javascript\" id=\"EventScriptBlock\">\n";
        myScript += "ShowProgressBar(35);"; //35 is dynamic value
        myScript += "\n\n </script>";
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myKey", myScript, false);
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
function ShowProgressBar(value) 
{
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
         value: value
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType(), "progressbar", "ShowProgressBar("+ 35 +");", True)
```